# How can I add an SSH key in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I am trying generate and add an SSH key to GitLab to access my old project to my new machine. What is proper workflow?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/ maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the [link](http://git.hifx.in/help/ssh/README#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair).

Command for generation:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your.email@example.com" -b 4096
```

Command for copy:

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```